# 404 Error Express Routing

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I can't work out where I'm going wrong with this simple routing task. When I go to localhost:3030/staff, I'm getting "Cannot GET /staff" and a 404 error.

Here is my setup.

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3030;

const staffRouter = require('./routes/staffrouter.js');

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + './public'));

app.use('./staff', staffRouter);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.pug');
});

app.listen(port);
```

I have tried using the paths "/staff" in my GET/POST requests, but that doesn't work, and isn't how it's supposed to work according to the tutorial I'm doing. I'm really stuck.

/routes/staffrouter.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const staff = require('../staff').staff;
const urlEncoded = (express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('staff.pug', { 
        deptOptions: staff.populateSelectors('department'),
        posOptions: staff.populateSelectors('position'),
        empArray: staff.readWriteJSON()
    });
 });

// Add new staff obj
router.post('/', urlEncoded, function(req, res, next) {
    let sObj = req.body;
    let dataArray = staff.readWriteJSON();

    //console.log('data:', data);
    dataArray.push(new staff.Employee(
        sObj.fName, 
        sObj.lName, 
        sObj.staffNum, 
        sObj.department, 
        sObj.position, 
        sObj.email, 
        sObj.phone
     ));
    staff.readWriteJSON(dataArray)
    res.render('../views/staff.pug', { 
        deptOptions: staff.populateSelectors('department'),
        posOptions: staff.populateSelectors('position'),
        empArray: staff.readWriteJSON()
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: May be try '/staff' instead of './staff'

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. But thank you.

Comment: Why don't you directly use app.get('/staff', function(){}) instead of using a router. You can pass app as parameter in other file.

Comment: You most likely get that error within HTML tags; can you tell me the error stack server side in your terminal?

Comment: That's the odd thing, it's not giving an error stack.

Comment: what's the error you get on the server side? Do you see the GET request coming through with a 404 error or you get no response whatsoever from the server?

Comment: No response, but it looks like Sanjay has fixed it for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. The server does not log the error because it does not get the request, which means that there is a problem with the way the directory is setup and middleware paths are declared in app.js and in the router. I suggest you to review the directory and structure it properly as at the moment is a bit confusing. Add proper models and controllers in it. Also add as a good practice an [error-handling middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) straight after you `app.use` in `app.js`.

Comment: I've structured the directories exactly the same as the express generator. I do need to make an error handler though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrong scope change the order

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + './public'));
const staffRouter = require('./routes/staffrouter.js');
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Though I don't understand why. The routes folder isn't in public. Can you tell me what happened?

Comment: when you use the static middleware express looks at public folder the routes are inside public to make it avilable it must be static hope you got it

Comment: Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL.

Comment: I was having a similar issue where in my route folder the file was named `post.js` but I was using `posts.js` in `server.js` file, a typo mistake.